# Подтянуть цену в зависимости от марки машины

Tags: excel, open-office

К примеру есть ячейка с названием машины: *BMW*

Есть вторая ячейка с ее ценой: *1000*

**Задача**

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог в одной ячейки выбирать машину, а во второй показывалась ее цена. К примеру, я выбираю *Mercedes* C и во второй ячейке показывает ранее установленную на эту машину цену.

С *Open Office* не особо знаком.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь две раздельные задачи:

1. Выбор значения в ячейке из заранее заданного набора:
   Делается довольно несложно:

   ```
   Данные → Проверка → {Разрешить=Диапазон ячеек; Диапазон=<Столбец с названиями>}
   ```
2. Выбор цены в соответствии с указанной ячейкой:
   Можно сделать с помощью [VLOOKUP](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP):

   ```
   =VLOOKUP(<ячейка выбора>;<диапазон поиска>;<Номер столбца в диапазоне>)
   ```

Проверено для `LibreOffice-5.4.2.2`.

Answer (score 1):

Если значений небольшое количество, можно обойтись без таблицы соответствий, создав массив в формуле:

```
=ВПР(A2;{"BMW";20:"Mercedes C";15:"Ока";1000000};2;)

=ПРОСМОТР(2;1/(A2={"раз";"три";"два";"семь"});{1;3;2;7})
```

Comment: То что нужно их как раз немного !